# How to screencap the smaller display of Samsung Galaxy Fold using ADB 'screencap' command?

Tags: adb, shell, screenshots

I'm trying to take a screenshot of Samsung Galaxy Fold's smaller display.

I use

```
shell screencap -p /sdcard/testss1.png
```

but it only captures the main display ― which is off ― and gets a black image.

How to change the display used for capturing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The screencap command can be configured to capture a specific display using the option `-d`.

> -d: specify the physical display ID to capture.
>   See `dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --display-id` for valid display IDs.

The output of `dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --display-id` is a bit longer, therefore you can filter out the display ids:

```
dumpsys SurfaceFlinger --display-id | grep display_id
```

On my device I only have one display with display_id=0.

Therefore the final command looks like this (just replace display_id):

```
shell screencap -d <display_id> -p /sdcard/testss1.png
```

Comment: It worked. If anyone will face same problem - the Fold's smaller display ID is 5